# Windows XP doesn’t shutdown

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown

I cannot shutdown my computer: when I normally press the buttons <kbd>shutdown</kbd>, <kbd>restart</kbd>, <kbd>standby</kbd> nothing happens.

All the applications are actually closed and I've not done any particular thing with my computer today. Suddenly it doesn't want to respond to the shutdown buttons.

What can I do?

Comment: Does it shut down if you goto your start menu and select it that way?

Comment: if you open a command prompt, and type `shutdown -f -s -t 10` will it shutdown in 10 seconds? (-s = shutdown, -r = reboot, -f = force, -t = time in seconds)

Comment: Yes, exactly: "if I goto my start menu and select it that way" it does not respond to the buttons... Do you think that if I try to restart by prompt, next it will be ok?

Comment: @neoDev - By saying "Yes, exactly" it indicates your computer does shutdown if you issue that command.  Please clarify

Comment: Okay, so if restarting the normal way doesn't work, it seems some program or service is preventing your pc from shutting down. If you have programs open and you issue a shutdown, will at least these programs close?

Comment: @LPChip No programs opened, nothing. I dont understand why.. I've not done any particular thing with my computer today..

Comment: Can you start an empty notepad, then issue a shutdown, and tell us if notepad was closed? This is crucial to know.

Comment: @LPChip Now I've tried to create a txt file on my desktop, I've edited it, then: menu start -> shutdown buttons, but nothing happens..

Comment: @neoDev - Using the proper terms is important.  By "menu" you mean the `start menu`?

Comment: Perhaps you could do a system restore or a windows repair since it is XP

Comment: @EricF I was thinking of `sfc /scannow` first, but only if it indeed is his startmenu poweroptions failing, and not a program/service that is hanging. If it is a program, then usually a complete power off (including removing the power for 1 minute) is sufficient.

Comment: I agree. That is a better option. I was just trying to think of a solution that will for sure fix it. neoDev definitely try what he says first and then what I said second :)

Comment: I've also tried the prompt.. (`shutdown -r`) NOthing happens. Now have I to try `sfc /scannow`?

Comment: In all this time, has your pc been shut down once? or is it possible an application is still hanging this time? If so, hold the powerbutton for 5 seconds first and make sure the pc is powered down completely. (not a restart, a full power down)

Comment: @neoDev:  Thanks for closing the loop on this question.  Being a Q&A site, the conventions are a little different from a forum.  The format relies on questions being questions and answers being solutions.  Embedding the solution in the question sort of messes with the system.  Can you move the solution to an answer?  Also, the site doesn't use [solved] in the title.  Instead, click the checkmark to accept your own answer.

Comment: Same issue for me. I reinstalled and it started happening again. Windows XP Pro.

Answer (score 3):

Open up a Command Prompt Window by Pressing `Windows` + `R`.

Type `shutdown -s -t 0 -f`.

Your computer shuts down!

(You could change `0` to the time in seconds after which you want Windows to shutdown)

Comment: Although this works, its not the solution to his problem, but a workaround.

Comment: The question is `" What can I do? "`

Comment: Yes, he obviously wants an answer to solve it once and for all, not find a way to shutdown his pc. You can also say: hold down the powerbutton for 5 seconds and the pc will go off. really not what you want, but it works too, doesn't it?

Comment: `Shut down`, not `Power off` directly, isn't it what he is asking for?

Comment: Change the answer to put the command into a batch file, have him put the batch file in the start menu. Voila, one button shutdown.

Comment: No power off. I mean "start -> menu -> buttons"

Comment: @EBGreen and again, this is a workaround. A better one, but still a workaround. Force-closing to shutdown can have average effects on the long run, so its not recommended as permanent solution.

Comment: Please edit your question appropriately :)

Comment: What 'kind' of effects @LPChip ?

Comment: Lets say you are editing a word document that is not saved. Shutdown normally is prevented and you can save your word document. Now the force shutdown will make you loose precious work. Additionally if your pc becomes slow, and you force-close shutdown, it is possible that files become corrupted. You could be looking at your webbrowsers profile not saving correctly, etc, meaning you have to setup your webbrowser again. you loose the tabs you have open, etc.

Comment: One could have `shutdown -a` handy for it.

Comment: I am not sure the reason this answer is getting downvotes.  The question isn't exactly clear.  The user says his computer won't shutdown, except, this command actually does shut the computer down.  Additionally there is little difference between this command and the `Shut down` option in the `Start Menu`.  In reality, they do exactly the samething, just with different arguments.

Comment: Exactly @Ramhound

Comment: @LPChip, provide a better answer. That is how superuser works. If you have a suggestion to improve this answer that works too. Ultimately the OP decides if this answer is best or another. So if this one is a problem for you provide a better one.

Comment: @EBGreen I want to solve his problem, not provide an answer that might not work. Therefor I wait for his reply if shutting down with notepad open closes notepad or not.

Comment: But you didn't just wait. You criticized someone else's answer that may or may not work fine for the OP.

Comment: @EBGreen One way or the other, this answer is a workaround, not a permanent solution. I've had people resort to workarounds and then came to me with all kinds of weird problems which were side-effects of workarounds. I learned the hard way that a problem cannot be permanently solved using workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Because the question itself is not 100% clear, this is what I was able to make of it so far.

All of the sudden, when you go to the start menu, and press shutdown, and you get the shutdown box, you choose one of the options, and press OK, but nothing happens.

My first suggestion is to try again with Notepad open to see if at least notepad is being closed or not.

This will indicate if shutdown is being blocked by a program that is not responding and keeps the system active, and/or if a system component is damaged which prevents you to do this.

My recommendation is to hold the power button for 5 seconds until the PC is fully powered off. Unplug the power cord and press the power button once to ensure that all power in the system is gone. Wait 5 seconds and plug in the power cord.

Start up your system and check if the shutdown options work now. If so, it was a program/service that crashed. If this happens again, you should look into what program is hanging and why it does. If not, it was just an event happening once.

If you can't shutdown at this time though, a system component is corrupted.

Start a command prompt and type in: `sfc /scannow`. This command will check all system components and fixes any issues there may be.

Comment: @ LPChip http://superuser.com/questions/819271/windows-xp-doesnt-shutdown?noredirect=1#comment1073549_819271

Answer (score -1):

You will want to look in your BIOS settings. Most have an option that dictates the functionality of front PWR and RESET buttons for a chassis. Make sure they are setup properly so that the PWR handles a shutdown and RESET resetting of course.  Since you indicated that it will shut down through windows and it is just the buttons that don't work I would recommend this.

Also check that the buttons are still physically plugged into the motherboard.  If you had it for years and all of a sudden this is happening, the wires could have come loose.  Open up your computer case, and locate on the motherboard the pins that do this. It could help to have your motherboard manual for this. Ensure tha the two wires coming from the front button are going to the PWR pins. Do the same for the RESET wires.

Comment: He says the windows startmenu shutdown options don't work.

Comment: My mistake. I thought he said it DID work by his "yes exactly"

Comment: @EricF - I am not sure, why you even bring up the buttons on the case, author even in the lack of clarity indicates his problem exists within the software itself.

Comment: All three buttons he mentioned can be found on certain towers. Calm down, I was trying to help based on what he had initially asked.